# reload tableview does not show all objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

in my code there is a loop which goes to an Array and adds all of the objects inside this array into another array. The objects inside the second Array are what is shown inside the tableview. So every time I go through the loop I append the object to the second array. After that loop I reload the tableview, but sometimes it does not show all the objects?! I think it's because it starts reload code gets executed even if the appending-process hasn't finished yet? How can I reload the tableview AFTER everything else is done? 
Here is my code, I am using Parse, so the query is from a parse server and gives me back an array. matesIdsAndNames is a dictionary, the rest are arrays.

```
if mateUserObject.isEmpty == false{

    for mateId in mateUserObject{



        let date = NSDate()
        let dateInt = date.timeIntervalSince1970

        let query = PFQuery(className: "calendarEvents")
        query.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: mateId)
        query.whereKey("StartDate", lessThan: dateInt)
        query.whereKey("EndDate", greaterThan: dateInt)
        query.cachePolicy = .NetworkOnly
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil{
                print(error)
            }else{

                if objects?.isEmpty == true{
                    self.freeMateIds.append(mateId.objectId!)
                    print(self.freeMateIds)
                    if self.mateUserObject.last == mateId{


                        if self.freeMateIds.isEmpty == false{


                            for freeMate in self.freeMateIds{

                                let oneFreeMate = self.matesIdsAndNames[freeMate]
                                self.freeMateNames.append(oneFreeMate!)
                                print(self.freeMateNames)
                            }

                        }
                        self.MatesTableView.reloadData()

                    }

                }

            }


        })



    }


}
```

}

Comment: I strongly suggest you edit this question and add some code. If your question is easier to read and has specific code, you'll 1) get more eyeballs on it and 2) get better answers.

Comment: I would improve the question by posting the relevant sections of your code (not your whole source file of course)

Comment: Read into Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) you will find the answer to your question... and/or post a question showing the code you are referring to

Comment: I just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

You're adding objects to an array from multiple background processes, but swift arrays are not thread safe. One option is to Google "swift thread safe array" and use some of the sample code provided.